# How to enable parsing yaml using yamldotnet which accepts both list and keyvalue pairs under same name?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I have a yaml where both of the following formats are acceptable -

```
  args:
    buildno: 1
    gitcommithash: cdc3b19
```

And

```
  args:
    - buildno=1
    - gitcommithash=cdc3b19
```

With current `YamlDotnet` configuration,

```
[YamlMember(Alias = "args")]
public Dictionary<string, string> Args { get; set; }
```

I can parse when the yaml is of format no. 1.
How can I modify my `YamlDotNet` code to accept both formats?
i.e. Accepting list as well as Dictionary for Args?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to create a class that implements both `IDictionary<string, string>` and `IList<string>`. You could try inheriting from `Dictionary<string, string>` and implement the list interface. I think it would be enough to implement the Add method from IList, where you split the string by the `=` character and add to the dictionary.

There are other ways but this is the simplest.